# Refresh a Loader when data is changed - android

Tags: java, android, refresh, loader, android-loadermanager

I user LoaderManager and CursorLoader to load the data from my database using a ContentProvider.
Now, the initial load is fine. I have a ListView that display all the rows from the DB(only the names-String adapter).

Now, when I add/delete a row from the database, I want to refresh the ListView so it will display the recent changes.

Currently I just restart the loader with the method "restartLoader" whenever a change is commited but I want to ask if there is another way of doing this without restarting the loader.

Here is my activity class code:
package com.silverfix.phony.activities;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.silverfix.phony.R;
import com.silverfix.phony.contentprovider.PhonyContentProvider;
import com.silverfix.phony.database.RingtonesTable;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnCreateContextMenuListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RingtonesActivity extends Activity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    private final int PICK_RINGTONE_CODE = 1;
    private final int CURSOR_LOADER_ID = 1;
    private final int EDIT_ID = 1;
    private final int DELETE_ID = 2;
    private String[] ContextCommands;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> ringtones;
    private ListView listview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ringtones);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_ringtone);
        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, PICK_RINGTONE_CODE);
            }
        });
        fillData();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) {
        super.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        switch (arg0) {
        case 1: // PICK_RINGTONE_CODE
            if (arg1 == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri ringtoneURI = arg2.getData();
                String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ringtoneURI,
                        projection, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int column = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                String displayName = cursor.getString(column);
                addRingtone(ringtoneURI, displayName);
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ringtones, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void fillData() {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(CURSOR_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        ringtones = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ringtones);
        ContextCommands = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.commands);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                editRingtone();
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(listview);
        listview.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                if (v.getId()==R.id.list) {
                    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
                    menu.setHeaderTitle(ContextCommands[info.position]);
                    String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.commands);
                    menu.add(Menu.NONE, EDIT_ID, 0, menuItems[0]);
                    menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE_ID, 0, menuItems[1]);
                  }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case EDIT_ID:
            editRingtone();
            return true;
        case DELETE_ID:
            String name = adapter.getItem(((AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo()).position);
            getContentResolver().delete(PhonyContentProvider.RINGTONES_URI, RingtonesTable.COLUMN_NAME
                    + "='" + name + "'", null);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void editRingtone() {
        Intent i = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, PICK_RINGTONE_CODE);
    }

    private void addRingtone(Uri uri, String name) {
        String[] projection = { RingtonesTable.COLUMN_NAME };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                PhonyContentProvider.RINGTONES_URI, projection,
                RingtonesTable.COLUMN_NAME + "='"+name+"'", null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(RingtonesTable.COLUMN_NAME, name);
            values.put(RingtonesTable.COLUMN_URI, uri.toString());
            getContentResolver().insert(PhonyContentProvider.RINGTONES_URI,
                    values);
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(CURSOR_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You already picked that ringtone!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String[] projection = {RingtonesTable.COLUMN_ID, RingtonesTable.COLUMN_NAME, RingtonesTable.COLUMN_URI};
        return new CursorLoader(this, PhonyContentProvider.RINGTONES_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        swapCursor(null);
    }

    private void swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            ringtones.clear();
            for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(RingtonesTable.COLUMN_NAME);
                ringtones.add(cursor.getString(column));
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            cursor.close();
            return;
        }
        ringtones.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have access to the loader, you may not expect that much of a change, but another way of implementing this is by having the cursor setting PhonyContentProvider.RINGTONES_URI as its notification uri and notifying the uri whenever the database data changes.

Relevant methods:
[setNotificationUri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#setNotificationUri(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri))
[notifyChange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange(android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver))

Comment: This only works for CursorLoader that takes it's data from ContentProvider which are registered for notification changes.. For other kinds of Loaders, this does not work!